# How do I Use This Code to Enlarge Multiple Images in Photo Gallery Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

I have about 40 images in the body of my code and would like to make the javascript code work with the photo gallery I have made.

The below code is from W3 Schools

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

If anyone can show me how to adjust this code so it will work the same for all 40 images in my photo gallery as it does here for the first image or the one image in the above W3 schools link.

I have tried giving them all the "img01" id tag, I thought about using a for loop; but, am not sure how to code this within the javascript.  I also tried using the document.getElementsByClassName code; but, that did not work either.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here are some of the images tags I use within the body; but, only the first pic in the gallery gets larger.

```
     <img id="myImg" src="apartment1.jpg" alt="apartment buiding" style="width:100%">
     <img id="myImg" src="apartment2.jpg" alt="other side of building" style="width:100%">
     <img id="myImg" src="aparment3.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

This is the css code

```
     img id="myImg"

     #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

     /* The Modal (background) */
     .modal {
       display: none; /* Hidden by default */
       position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
       z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
       padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
       width: 100%; /* Full width */
       height: 100%; /* Full height */
       overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
       background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
     }

     /* Modal Content (image) */
      .modal-content {
       margin: auto;
       display: block;
       width: 80%;
       max-width: 700px;
     }

     /* Caption of Modal Image */
      #caption {
       margin: auto;
       display: block;
       width: 80%;
       max-width: 700px;
       text-align: center;
       color: #ccc;
       padding: 10px 0;
       height: 150px;
      }

      /* Add Animation */
       .modal-content, #caption {  
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
     }

     @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
       from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
       to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
      }

     @keyframes zoom {
        from {transform: scale(0.1)} 
        to {transform: scale(1)}
     }

     /* The Close Button */
     .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
      color: #f1f1f1;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: 0.3s;
     }

     .close:hover,
     .close:focus {
        color: #bbb;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
     }
```

This is the JavaScript code

```
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                <span class="close">×</span>
                 <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                 <div id="caption"></div>
            </div>


    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a 
    caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
     img.onclick = function(){
       modal.style.display = "block";
       modalImg.src = this.src;
       captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
     }

     // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
     var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatup,

Can't you just give each  tag a class and adjust the size of the images with width or height? I'm not sure if that what you are trying to ask.

also it may have been an careless mistake that you rewrote each image's id to repeat and to be the same.

Comment: In regards to the class,I tried changing                                                                                         
         '''var modalmg = document.getElementsByClassName("resize");'''                           
but was not able to get it to work.  Originally I tried setting all the img to the same id="img01" so when its clicked on it does the same thing; but, that would not work either.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things need to improve over here.

1. Html tags need to change ID to class, because ID is present or point to one Html tag only. If you want to call or point to multiple Html tag you must use class. And please give some "readable" name, do not use myImg or img01.

```
<img class="apartmentImage" src="apartment1.jpg" alt="apartment buiding" style="width:100%">
<img class="apartmentImage" src="apartment2.jpg" alt="other side of building" style="width:100%">
<img class="apartmentImage" src="aparment3.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

2. In the Css code, I found that why you give different value for zoom animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
       from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
       to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
      }

     @keyframes zoom {
        from {transform: scale(0.1)} 
        to {transform: scale(1)}
     }
```

- Please use original from W3schools

```
@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}
```

3. Javascript:

- I will repeat again, USE READABLE AND UNDERSTANDABLE NAME for html tag. Lets change to apartmentImage (you can use different name if you want). Because you need to read multiple images, you need to read class name. But the Hard part is detect what image you clicked. And then add the image content like the original.

```
// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var apartmentImage = document.getElementsByClassName("apartmentImage");
var myModalImg = document.getElementById("myModalImg");
var myModalImgCaptionText = document.getElementById("myModalImgCaption");

document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    var clickedEl = window.event ? event.srcElement : e.target;
    while (clickedEl != null) {
        if (clickedEl.className && (" " + clickedEl.className + " ").indexOf("apartmentImage") != -1) {
            modal.style.display = "block";
            myModalImg.src = clickedEl.src;
            myModalImgCaptionText.innerHTML = clickedEl.alt;
            return;
        }
        clickedEl = clickedEl.parentNode;
    }
}
```

- Finally, as I recommend above you should use readable name and name must relate to the value, don't do this `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` do this instead `var closeTag = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];`

Here the code https://jsfiddle.net/giang_dlinh92/ojbLedyr/16/

Comment: This new code only allows the first image to open inside a black box; but, it does not enlarge it or have include the alt caption.  For the first picture once clicked on it aligns it in on the left in a black box, once I click on it, then close, then click again, it opens the black box and adds the same image to it so there are two, close, click again, then three ect..  Additionally, the original Id="myImg" tag allowed the pictures to change when the mouse hovered over top of them.  The original code I posted worked perfectly; but, would only allow the first picture to enlarge.

Comment: Is there any reason why var apartmentImages = document.querySelectorAll('.apartmentImage'); is .apartmentImage instead of just apartmentImage without the . before the a?

Comment: ok, I think I had misunderstood your intent. I had create jsfiddle for your question, you can take a look. About the document.querySelectorAll() , that is the syntax, It require specific name of type of the html tag. ID or Class name, you choice. if it the ID name, you want to use '#' before ID name.
Here the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/giang_dlinh92/ojbLedyr/15/

Comment: Yes, this works well.  Thank you for all your help!  The use of the # before the ID name allowed me to apply the hover shadow to all of the images.  I also found a W3 Schools link for a lightbox image gallery using modals that helped out too.  Thanks again!  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid using the same ID
2. And yes, loop the element

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
for (let i = 0, img; img = imgs[i]; i++) {
  img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}
/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img class="myImg" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals" alt="animals" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<img class="myImg" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/arch" alt="arch" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<img class="myImg" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/nature" alt="nature" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```